# Click all links on the website with action. The element reference is stale er

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I make new script, I want click() all listed links on the website, find something, back to the listed links, click() next link, find something, back to the listed links.

I start with website which list for me some links:

link 1
link 2
link 3
etc

```
links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("myxpath")
for link in links:
    link.click()
    try:
        time.sleep(2)
        wantedelement = driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath")
        wantedelement.click()
        #Save to file
        tofile = driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath")
        print (tofile.text)
        myfile = open("file.txt", "a")
        my.write(tofile.text + "\n")
        driver.back()
except (ElementNotVisibleException, NoSuchElementException):
        driver.back()
```

But my script check only one link and when back to the listed links print me error:

selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: The element reference is stale. Either the element is no longer attached to the DOM or the page has been refreshed.

```
on line:
for link in links:
    link.click() <----
```

How can i fix it? (Python 2.7)

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

Don't use delays like "sleep" to synchronize.  Use "wait" conditions instead.

Since you are using "back()" you will want to only do that if you successfully moved off the previous page, which is one of the reasons that it is better to test the actions specifically - for example, how do you know that every click() is supposed to move you "forward", might be some other action involved.  You are making assumptions about the DOM, here, which is OK, but you'll need to check your conditions before performing other actions.  For example if you move "back" before your next page is loaded you will lose your DOM.

Also, it is possible that the back() is causing your DOM to refresh, which is changing the element identifiers.  If that's the case you'll want to verify your page after each back and iterate through the elements by index, looking them up individually before clicking.

I always have found it better practice to be more exacting about things like click operations.  Click the **specific** link and check for the **specific** result - and use wait conditions between actions to assure you are exactly where you expect to be.

More about [wait conditions here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html).

Comment: Why wait() is better than sleep()? And i instead not know how i can click() all links :) Do you can show me example? It's the same like google search and click all results. Sorry for my english

Comment: @PythonLearn - The reason you want to use a `wait()` over a sleep is that it doesn't affect the thread your code is running on; you are just telling your `driver` object to, "hold on a minute."  When you use `sleep` you are putting the _thread_ to sleep.  And that can cause oddities and slow down the execution time of your tests.

Comment: A "sleep" does not guarantee that the desired condition has been met.  It just delays things from happening.  All test actions should have expected results, and "waits" allow you to wait for the all the loading and rendering and stuff to complete.  Waits have timeouts in case things don't happen correctly.

When testing use "[waits](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)" not sleep, and the condition will either be satisfied or not.  When not you will need to check if the page changed or not.

Comment: Seriously no examples? Maybe open all links in new tab?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a Python programmer; I do have extensive experience with Selenium web drivers and running browser testing scenarios.  It really is philosophical anyhow - because the specifics of the waits and sequencing are different in different scenarios.  See the link provided for details about "wait conditions" in Python - there are a lot of them!